# How to delete a row in datatable using linq to dataset?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ado.net, dataset

I have table(`Color`) in DataSet(`dsObjets`).

I want to remove specific row(specific `ColorID`) from this table.

Any idea how can I implement this with help of LINQ?

Comment: Did you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1):

Here is more information on deleting records:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386925.aspx

To delete a row in the database:

- Query the database for the row to be deleted.
- Call the DeleteOnSubmit method.
- Submit the change to the database.

Comment: I want to delete from DataSet not from dataBase!

Comment: This should be a comment unless you write here some explanation yourself. The link could die in the future and this answer will be useless.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var results = from row in dsObjects.Tables["Color"].AsEnumerable()
          where row.Field<int>("ColorID") == <color ID to be removed> 
          select row;
foreach (DataRow row in results)
{
   dsObjects.Tables["Color"].Remove(row);
}
```